# Using random how do you generate pseudorandom numbers with no decimals?

Tags: python

Using the current code that is below this code will create a random number with a massive amount of decimals. Example: 8.71763761465. I'm guessing that there is a way to generate numbers with no decimal, I just don't know how. How do you generate numbers without massive amounts of decimals? Thank you.

```
import random
randint = random.uniform(1, 10)
print (randint)
```

Comment: `random.randint(1, 10)`?

Comment: Replace your line with the line provided above by @sacul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just cast it to an int?

```
import random
randint = int(random.uniform(1, 10))
print(randint)
```

Or, more appropriately, just use `randint`:

```
import random
randint = random.randint(1, 10)
print (randint)
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I knew there was a way to do it, I just didn't know what way.

Comment: `int(random.uniform(1, 10))` generates a pseudorandom integer uniformly from `[1, 2, ..., 9]`, whereas `random.randint(1, 10)` generates a pseudorandom integer uniformly from `[1, 2, ..., 10]`. The difference is because `random.randint(a, b)` is an alias for `random.randrange(a, b+1)`. You could use `round(random.uniform(1, 10))` to achieve the same effect as `random.randint(1, 10)` since rounding doesn't carry the same bias as flooring with the `int` function.